# How to remove cardview padding?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-cardview

I'm developing an android app and I have a cardview on my xml to make the pictures circular. Although I could change the color of the cardview itself, I'm having a hard time removing the strange dark padding that comes with it:
[image: strange padding]

My code is below:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/profilePictureCircle"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="260dp"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="false"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorBottomNavigationApp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/profileName"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/profileName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/chosen_picture"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/camera" />
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

I've tried several things and none seemed to work. Can anyone help please?
Thanks!

Comment: I was using the same thing too, but then I found https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView and it helped me to get rid of a lot of troubles. You can give it a chance.

Comment: use cardElevation 0

Comment: cardElevation 0 worked!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that cardElevation should be set to 0